# How do I make an SQL query operate on a data subset without repeating myself?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with app statistics, let’s say the columns are `os_version` and `app_id` (simplifying). I want to list all OS versions for a certain app, and for each OS version I want to see a number of records that have at least this OS version. Example data:

```
app1 1.0
app1 2.0
app2 1.0
```

Now for `app1` I want to see:

```
version | score | comments
--------+-------+---------
1.0     | 2     | there are two records having OS at least 1.0
2.0     | 1     | there is just one record with OS at least 2.0
```

Now, pardon my ignorant SQL, but I have come up with this query:

```
SELECT
    os_version,
    -- number_of_records_having_at_least_this_version / number_of_all_records
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats WHERE app_id='app1' AND os_version >= outer.os_version)/ 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats WHERE app_id='app1') AS score
FROM (SELECT * FROM stats WHERE app_id='app1') AS outer
GROUP BY os_version;
```

This is crazy, as I have to filter by the app ID three times. Is it possible to filter by the app ID first and then use the resulting row set for further operations? Without a temporary table? In SQLite? Something like:

```
SELECT
    os_version,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filtered WHERE os_version >= filtered.os_version)/
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filtered) AS score
FROM (SELECT * FROM stats WHERE app_id='app1') AS filtered
GROUP BY os_version;
```

…which, sadly, does not work.

Comment: The real problem is how to write SQL code that identifies that `'1.0'` is earlier version that `'2.0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if I've understood the question properly, that something like this should do the trick..

```
SELECT
    s1.app_id,
    s1.os_version,
    count(*)
FROM stats s1 INNER JOIN stats s2 ON s1.app_id = s2.app_id 
                                  AND s2.os_version >= s1.os_version
GROUP BY s1.app_id, s1.os_version
```

EDIT: This returns results fitered by app_id (as with the example query in the question)

```
SELECT
    s1.app_id,
    s1.os_version,
    count(*)
FROM stats s1 INNER JOIN stats s2 ON s1.app_id = s2.app_id 
                                  AND s2.os_version >= s1.os_version
WHERE s1.app_id = 'app1'
GROUP BY s1.app_id, s1.os_version
```

EDIT2:

```
SELECT
    s1.app_id,
    s1.os_version,
    count(*)
FROM stats s1 INNER JOIN stats s2 ON s1.app_id = s2.app_id 
                                  AND s2.os_version >= s1.os_version
                                  AND s1.app_id = 'app1'
GROUP BY s1.app_id, s1.os_version
```

EDIT3: To get round the 2.11 < 2.7 problem

```
SELECT
    s1.app_id,
    s1.os_version,
    count(*)
FROM stats s1 INNER JOIN stats s2 ON s1.app_id = s2.app_id 
              AND CAST(REPLACE(s2.os_version, '.', '') TO INTEGER) >= 
                  CAST(REPLACE(s1.os_version, '.', '') TO INTEGER)
              AND s1.app_id = 'app1'
GROUP BY s1.app_id, s1.os_version
```

Comment: This looks promising, but does not yield any results in a reasonable timeframe on my machine :) The query mentioned in the question finishes almost immediately.

Comment: Strange, assuming you have indexes on your id and version columns, then this is about as performant as you can get.. I've tested on a table with ~40k records and it returns almost immediately for me.. It should be quicker if you filter on the app_id, but I'm not sure if thats what you want?

Comment: I’m an SQL noob, so it’s quite possible that I am doing something incredibly stupid. There’s around 800k rows in the table. I’ll check the indexes.

Comment: looks good to me.  Adding 'app1' in a where clause will filter by app_id too

Comment: How will `s2.os_version >= s1.os_version` work with `'2.11' >= '2.7'` ?

Comment: @ypercube, I can pre-process the incoming data if necessary, so that’s not a big problem. After some playing with the indexes I got the query to work, but it’s still *much* slower than the original one and the `COUNT(*)` expression counts all rows in the table, not just those from `app1`. (In my example above it would print `3` for `1.0`, since it also consideres `app2`.) Is it possible to limit the join only to `app1`? Because it looks like now the `WHERE` clause only filters the rows after everything is done.

Comment: The count(*) will only count the rows in the group i.e. count per appid/osversion combination.. You could try adding the filter to the join clause, that might improve the performance a bit.. See my edit..

Comment: I wrote a simple test case that works fine with your query, so I’ll just have to find out what I’m doing wrong in the production DB. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ypercube: have updated again with a nasty solution for your 2.11 < 2.7 point.. Although I think in cases like this, seperate columns for minor/major revisions is probably a better way to go..